# Are there software to simulate timing diagrams for serial communication circuits?

Tags: digital-communications, serial-bus

For the purpose of learning(not necessarily designing), I want to simulate basic **serial communication ICs** such as MAX485 or MAX232. An example circuit can be as follows:

[image]

Now instead of building this circuit and using logic analyzers is there any category of simulation tools where one can see **timing diagrams** such as in below fashion?(I don't know what to look for or keyword):

[image]

(LTspice is free and great for analog/linear circuit simulations but it won't help with this type of circuitry since there is no SPICE model)

Comment: Pretty sure Proteus can do that.

Comment: Do you want to see the "delay varies" part of the diagrams, the gray sections? I don't think any simulator will show that.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I dont need to see those then, its fine as much as I can see. My purpose is to use that as part of self learning.

Comment: Google "digital logic simulator", you'll get a bunch of hits.

Comment: Note that asynchronous serial communication is, by its nature, not very precise in timing. To learn about timing I would recommended you study a synchronous data channel.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/speters/cbe0aab8cdb150338410

Comment: The MAX232 and MAX485 are just level converters - they don't generate or decode the serial data streams.  The serial data stream is created by a UART (Universal Asynchronous Receiver-Transmitter) or often these days, by a UART peripheral block inside a microcontroller.

Comment: What are you trying to get out of this effort?  If you're doing all-digital design, then this is what Verilog and VHDL are **for** -- write a test bench that generates asynchronous serial, and apply that to your UART.  If you're doing analog design, then make a piecewise-continuous waveform and run it through whatever analog circuitry you want.